# EJB Creation and Deployment in Jboss5 using EAR

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb-3.0

I am trying to integrate EJB module in my web application. Already have one EJB in that project. while starting my server the recently add EJB didn't start

```
00:27:07,627 INFO  [ComponentRegistry] JBoss Cache version: JBossCache 'Malagueta' 3.2.11.GA
00:27:08,792 INFO  [JBossASKernel] Created KernelDeployment for: sample02EJB.jar
00:27:08,804 INFO  [JBossASKernel] installing bean: jboss.j2ee:ear=sample02.ear,jar=sample02EJB.jar,name=sampleMDB01,service=EJB3
00:27:08,804 INFO  [JBossASKernel]   with dependencies:
00:27:08,805 INFO  [JBossASKernel]   and demands:
00:27:08,805 INFO  [JBossASKernel]  jboss.ejb:service=EJBTimerService
00:27:08,805 INFO  [JBossASKernel]  com.amfam.jbossha:service=ActiveMessageProcessingBarrier
00:27:08,805 INFO  [JBossASKernel]   and supplies:
00:27:08,805 INFO  [JBossASKernel]  jndi:null
00:27:08,805 INFO  [JBossASKernel]  Class:javax.jms.MessageListener
00:27:08,805 INFO  [JBossASKernel] Added bean(jboss.j2ee:ear=sample02.ear,jar=sample02EJB.jar,name=sampleMDB01,service=EJB3) to KernelDeployment of: sample02EJB.jar
00:27:09,023 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: com.cpt.integration.service.dao.sampleMDBBean01 ejbName: sampleMDB01
```

What should I do to start my new ejb as like above

Comment: Is there an error in the log?

Comment: There is no error in log

Comment: Please post your EJB code.

Comment: @KennethClark There is no problem with EJB code. I need to know how to start my new ejb as like it console and also want to know about integrating EJB with EAR

Comment: How did you add this EJB?

Comment: @Evan Knowles  In application.xml added as <module> <ejb>sample02EJB.jar</ejb> </module>

Comment: Could you please anyone tell us how to add multiple ejbs in single EAR